# order or adjuncts and adjectives

Tags: nouns, adjectives, word-order

The more thought I give about the order of adjuncts and adjectives before a noun, the less sense it all makes. Not a native speaker, but using English on a daily basis.

For instance, in "Relational database management system", does Relational determine the system, the database or the database management?

Similarly, in "Monthly progress report", is the progress report monthly, or just the progress?

Finally, if we take "plastic food container" vs "organic food container", it is easy to identify what determines what, but in some highly technical texts, I can not always figure out the sequence.

Any rules that would apply?

Thanx,
Gj

Comment: In the face of potential ambiguity, hyphenate: a "plastic food container" is not a "plastic-food container." Most people don't hyphenate compound adjectives in this way anymore, though, and so much ambiguity is present in such constructions. If the writer won't do a little work, the reader sometimes has to do a lot of head-scratching.

Comment: Yes. Not all sweet shop-girls are sweet-shop girls.

Comment: Of course, one can't hyphenate or punctuate at all in real English. In English speech, these contrasts iron out because they're spoken differently, with different stress and intonation. Punctuation is possible only in English writing, and there it's even more troublesome, because English orthography is such a crappy system. If you're writing, try to say it out loud to hear it, then try to imitate that intonation and stress in writing. If you can. That's what everybody else does.

Comment: "*[Relational database]* management system" <-- It is a management system that manages a relational database. (There are many types of databases, a relational one is one kind of them.) This is what I would expect it to mean. (Though it could maybe be possible that the database is not a relational one, but the management system provides an interface that makes it seem as though the underlying database is relational; but that would be quite inefficient.)

Answer (score -1):

In the specific examples that you posted, the adjective modifies or categorizes the phrase the follows.  A "Relational database management system" is a type of database management system.  A monthly progress report would be a progress report that is issued monthly.

This is not true in all cases.

Comment: Actually, it is not even true in this case. [Relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) is a single unit. So what we have here is *not* a type of database management system, as you suggest. We are not looking at a relational system for managing databases, but at a system for managing relational databases.